# OracleConnection Memory Leak

Tags: c#, oracle, memory, odp.net

I am getting memory growing and growing, on the long run (hours, days) in the following code.

```
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
for (int i = 1; i < 20; i++)
{
 int j = i;
 tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
     {
        while (true)
        {
            OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(constr(j));      
            con.Open();
            con.Close();
            con.Dispose();
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
        }
    },TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning));
}
Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
```

So, in short: I have 20 ( for example) Databases and want to connect to them in separate Tasks....and also I would need to open/close connection each time.
When running this for a hours, days...the memory is growing...and that is not acceptable

Using .NET 4.0 and ODP version 4.121.2.0

Any idea how to have permanent open/close activity in lot of parallel tasks, on many different databases without memory problem?

Comment: What objects are kept alive? Have you ran some memory profiling tools to find out? It is better use `using` by the way and use proper exception handling. Mixing tasks and `Thread.Sleep` is another horrible idea.

Comment: what is `constr(j)`, seem suspicious.

Comment: I used some memory profilers and it say that the unmanaged memory is growing. Out of my tests, it is all connected with con.Open() statement, so it somehow comes from Oracle driver. Thread.Sleep is not impeort here...just put it to have some break....to make less preasere on the code...but can bbe removed...so it is present just in this test code

Comment: As already mentioned use the using statement as it's generally safer than explicitly calling dispose and also dispose calls close. I can tell what the problem is by looking. Each tasks runs forever because you declared while (true) and that means 20 tasks are repeatedly executing the sql for an infinite amount of time and the problem is probably that the garbage collector can't clean the garbage fast enough or that there's a lot of finalizations waiting to be executed.

Comment: Back in 2005, I found that the Oracle.Net was NOT thread safe.  I don't know if this is still true.

Comment: this is a sample code...but the idea is simple. I have N databases and have permanently and frequently to open and close connections to them.....for that purpose I want to allocate M threads/tasks.........and, the memory problem comes on the long run

Comment: Post your actual code because this code it's too much garbage

Comment: constr(j) is just to build a connectionstring for the Database j..can be ignored here.....also Thread.Sleep......also  using(..) can be added for OracleConnection.....nothing of that makes difference

Comment: About 'tasts that are running forever'..the first version was that each time I make a new task....but the the memory is growing much faster...so I changed that to have a task that do the action again and again....the the memory is growing much slower........but I will repeat.......can somebody suggest a different architecture for the mentioned problem.... N databases......to run for a months.......have to connect very frequently to each of them.....in the same time.....and everything to run again and again